# Include prebuilt shared library in Android AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I would like to use a prebuilt shared library (let's call it `libmylib.so`) from some AOSP code, for instance in the folder `framework/av/media/libmedia`.

Since my target is Nexus 7, I created a new folder `device/asus/flo/mylib`, where I put 2 files:

- `libmylib.so`
- `Android.mk`

My first try was to use `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` in `Android.mk` as follow:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libmylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libmylib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then, I added the dependency in the `libmedia` module (in `framework/av/media/libmedia/Android.mk`, I added `libmylib` to the `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` list).

Unfortunately, the build (`lunch aosp_flo-eng && make -j4`) failed:

```
*** No rule to make target `out/target/product/flo/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libmylib_intermediates/export_includes’, needed by `out/target/product/flo/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libmedia_intermediates/import_includes’. Stop.
```

---

Therefore, I replaced `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` by `BUILD_PREBUILT` (I don't really understand the difference):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libmylib
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libmylib.so
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

That way, the build succeeded.

So I flashed the image:

```
fastboot flashall -w
```

But unfortunately, the tablet did not boot. `adb logcat` printed indefinitely:

```
E SurfaceFlinger: error posting framebuffer: -22
E qdgralloc: fb_post: FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO for primary failed, str: Invalid argument
E SurfaceFlinger: error posting framebuffer: -22
E qdgralloc: fb_post: FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO for primary failed, str: Invalid argument
E SurfaceFlinger: error posting framebuffer: -22
E qdgralloc: fb_post: FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO for primary failed, str: Invalid argument
```

---

If I remove `libmylib` from `framework/av/media/libmedia/Android.mk`, everything is fine, the tablet boots correctly.

Note that I don't even call the library at this point, the simple fact to declare it as a `libmedia` dependency is problematic.

I tried with several `.so` (including one that I tested on the tablet with a binary calling a function it exposes, directly in `/data/local/tmp`, so the `.so` is ok).

I probably missed something. Any clue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested the same thing on Nexus 5, which is fortunately more verbose :)

The problem was that `LOCAL_MODULE` and `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` didn't use the same lib name (a problem that was not present in my original post, since I wanted to abstract the details).

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libmylib
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libsomething.so
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

The module was `libmylib`, but the source file was `libsomething.so`.

That way, there was a `/system/lib/libsomething.so`, but a `dlopen()` failed because `/system/lib/libmylib.so` was not found.

Using the same name for both solves the problem:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libsomething
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libsomething.so
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: how did you handle multiple lpatforms, i.e. 32 bit vs 64 libs? both will need to be installed.

Comment: Just as a hint  for the target architecture direction: `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfoo.so`
Source: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html

Comment: And there's this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180118/use-prebuilt-shared-library-in-android-aosp

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I was pointing LOCAL_SRC_FILES to my prebuilt .so file *inside* the libs folder. But you can't include the prebuilt .so file inside the libs folder because that is generated with each ndk-build.