# Android.mk build error export_includes needed by import_includes for prebuilt library

Tags: android, android-source

I am having issues creating a Android prebuilt shared library. In hope of figuring out what I'm doing wrong, I followed Google's [example](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts) where I found the source for this example in the android-8.1.0_r52 tree at development/ndk/tests/prebuilt-library/jni.

Here's how I configure the ASOP

- $ . build/envsetup.sh
- $ lunch (I selected 29 aosp_bullhead_userdebug)

Then in the above jni folder I issued "$ mm"

The error I get is (which is the same is my other project)

```
ninja: error: 'out/target/product/bullhead/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/foo-prebuilt_intermediates/export_includes', needed by 'out/target/product/bullhead/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/foo-user_intermediates/import_includes', missing and no known rule to make it
```

When I grep the out/target/products/bullhead folder for "*foo*" I get nothing.

I also tried replacing

> include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

with

> include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

and get the same error, but "obj" is replaced with "obj_arm".

Below is the stock Android.mk that comes with the tree.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Define BUILD_FOO=1 to rebuild libfoo.so from scratch, then
# copy obj/local/armeabi/libfoo.so to jni/libfoo.so
#
ifneq ($(BUILD_FOO),)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo/foo.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

else # not build libfoo.so, trying to use PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY instead.

# Note: the module is named foo-prebuilt, but the library is libfool.so !
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfoo.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo-user
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo-user.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := foo-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

endif
```

This is the jni/ directory structure

- jni/

  - Android.mk
  - foo-user.c
  - libfoo.so
  - foo/

    - foo.c
    - foo.h

Comment: **Android.mk** file **ALWAYS** (and **must**, in the same directory) come with a companion **Application.mk**  (you seem to be missing it) file (It's contents *should* look something like this *old* example: " **`#APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
APP_STL := stlport_static
#APP_OPTIM := debug`** "). Usual drill, show your **build.gradle** files/error logs/config files...

Comment: There is no Application.mk because this question isn't about the NDK, it's about the platform build system.

Comment: A solution was found using Android.bp (the Soong replacement for the Andoird make based built system). Unfortunately I am banned from answering questions, so I'll have to make this short.

Comment: the steps are: add the jni directory to the $(gettop)/Android.bp file, set "export BUILD_FOO=1", mm, cp $OUT/system/lib/foo.so to lib64/libfoo.so (also also same for lib/), convert the jni/Android.mk to Android.bp (I'd include it but I'm running out of characters), and finally mm.   The Soong builds the native application and places the foo-user executable in $(OUT)/bullhead/system/bin.

Answer (score 1):

check https://stackoverflow.com/a/35312125

change

```
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

to

```
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

worked for me, build with android build system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).